# How to install newer version of /usr/bin/host via Homebrew?

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, homebrew

My `host` command doesn't understand CAA records.

```
host -t CAA google.com
host: invalid type: CAA

which host
/usr/bin/host
```

how to install newer version of `/usr/bin/host` via Homebrew? In which package the host command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder /usr/bin/ is Apple's realm and protected by SIP. You have to wait until Apple provides an updated version of *host*.

AFAIK Homebrew doesn't provide a newer (or better: any) *host* executable.

So either use dig: `dig <host> type257` or install *[go](https://golang.org)* and [dnscaa - CAA DNS Library for Go](https://github.com/weppos/dnscaa).

Comment: can you describe how to install new dig? `dig also doesn’t support CAA inheritance, and the output of the query is the binary-encoded record (although in newer versions of dig, support for parsing the record data is present)`

Comment: @FyodorGlebov It's the same with *dig*: there's no dig receipt for brew. If you need caa inheritance you have to install go & dnscaa.